# How to push the data from Tableau to SQL Server without using CSV

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

We have fetched the data from SQL Server into Tableau. After adding some calculated fields we want to push the data back to SQL Server. How to achieve the same without using CSV?
Also are there any commands for tabcmd to achieve the same?

Comment: It sounds like you should approach this in a different way, as a Tableau data extract is not a ETL tool.

Comment: Thanks for your views. But we wanted to automate a process and hence trying to fetch additionally created fields from tableau to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Look into extensions. There are some examples here but you'll likely have to modify or rebuild to fit your needs. You'll also need some understanding of javascript/jquery to get extensions working. https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/

Comment: I researched but there is no such provision yet. Hope this feature will get added in future.